# manually enter value for <input> element

Tags: html

I have a hidden `input` element in my html-form.

I want to pass hard-coded value in it.

```
<input id="practiceName" type="hidden" name="practiceName" />
```

Should I add value="USR"?

and have another form take that `practiceName` to be "`USR`"

Comment: look up how getElementByID works in Javascript.

Comment: *'Should I add value="USR"?'* -- Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the value attribute as you suggested.

```
<input id="practiceName" type="hidden" name="practiceName" value="USR" />
```